# Changing from Prototype to jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have the following Prototype code which I want to change to jQuery.

It seems to me that except Ajax.Updater all other code can be used in jQuery. But I most probably wrong.

```
function jsUpdateCart(){
  var parameter_string = '';
  allNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("process");
  for(i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++) {
    var tempid = allNodes[i].id;
    var temp = new Array;
    temp = tempid.split("_");
    var real_id = temp[2];
    var real_value = allNodes[i].value;
    parameter_string += real_id +':'+real_value+',';
  }

  var params = 'ids='+parameter_string;
  var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
    'ajax_msg','http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_shopping/index.php/welcome/ajax_cart', {method:'post',parameters:params,onComplete:showMessage}
    );

}

function showMessage(req){
  $('ajax_msg').innerHTML = req.responseText;
  location.reload(true);
}


function jsRemoveProduct(id){
  var params = 'id='+id;
  var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
    'ajax_msg','http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_shopping/index.php/welcome/ajax_cart_remove', {method:'post',parameters:params,onComplete:showMessage}
    );

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look through the jQuery documentation on the [`ajax` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) would make it easy to convert your `Ajax.Updater` calls into the jQuery equivalent:

```
$.ajax( {
  type: 'post',
  url: "<your_long_url>/ajax_cart",
  data: params,
  success: function( r ) {
    $('#ajax_msg').html( r );
    location.reload( true );
  }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, except it will load the index page instead of the same page which is cart page. What do you suggest to change in order to reload the same page?

Comment: I don't follow your second question here. I just ported your code. Why do you need to refresh any page?

Comment: Original code takes me the page where I was. But your code takes me to index page. I thought it might be related to your code. I have to see my php.

Comment: I am sorry. Update works. My problem is that I changed function jsRemoveProduct to the following and it takes me to index. 
function jsRemoveProduct(id){
  var params = 'id='+id;
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_shopping/index.php/welcome/ajax_cart_remove",
   data: params,
   success: function( r ) {
    $('#ajax_msg').html( r );
    location.reload( true );
  }
 });
}

Comment: I found the problem. Delete uses a link. HTML is like this. <a href='#' onclick='jsRemoveProduct(8)'>delete</a>
And update uses INPUT. <input type='button' name='update' value='update' onclick='jsUpdateCart()'/>
If I use input for delete it works. But I'd like to know how to do it with a link.

Comment: You should be able to make your link work with it like so: `<a href='#' onclick='jsRemoveProduct(8);return false;'>delete</a>` or, what I would prefer personally: `<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='jsRemoveProduct(8);'>delete</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it seems to me that except Ajax.Updater and $('ajax_msg') all your code is pure javascript.
You'll have to use jquery's ajax and for your selector just use $('.ajax_msg') if it's a class or $("#ajax_msg") if id.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
function jsUpdateCart(){
    var parameter_string = '';

    $('.process').each(function(){
        var tempid = this.id, temp = tempid.split('_'), real_id = temp[2], real_value = this.value;
        parameter_string += real_id + ':'+real_value+',';
    });

    var params = 'ids='+parameter_string;
    $('#ajax_msg').load('http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_shopping/index.php/welcome/ajax_cart',data,
        function(){location.reload(true);});
}
```

It sounds like you could use a [starter course on jQuery](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jQuery/default.aspx). If it's new to you, it's worth reading up on it.